# what is the simplest way to get the value from periodic sequence 0,1,2,3,2,1,0,1... by index?

Tags: java, algorithm, math, language-agnostic

for example,I have a periodic sequence starts from 0,then 1,2,until 3, then starts drop to 2,1,then 0 and then 1 again. Lets the function be f(min,max,x),where x is the index,so:

```
f(0,3,0)=0
f(0,3,1)=1
f(0,3,2)=2
f(0,3,3)=3
f(0,3,4)=2
.
.
.
f(0,3,9)=3
```

I tried something like:

```
public static int f(int min,int max,int x){
    int r=min;
    int increment=1;
    for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
        if(r==max){
            increment=-1;
        }else if(r==min){
            increment=1;
        }
        r+=increment;
    }
    return r;
}
```

but I think it is quite long and ineffecient, is there more simple way to implement f(min,max,x)?

or can it be done by one line only such as int result=(some +-*/,mod,ternary operator... to min,max,x)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int f(int min, int max, int x) {
    const int len = (max - min) * 2;
    const int offset = (x + len - 1) % len;
    const int ans = (offset + 1) % len;
    return min + ans > max ? min + len - ans : min + ans;
}
```

Check it [live here](http://ideone.com/emYzyf)

Answer (score 1):

The solution as an explicit formula:

```
// note this doesn't work for negative values as expected
public static int f(int min,int max,int x) {
    return max-abs(x%((max-min)*2)-max+min)
}

// just add abs(x) to make it work for negative numbers
public static int f(int min,int max,int x) {
    return max-abs(abs(x)%((max-min)*2)-max+min)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int index = x % (2*(max-min)); // take care of periodicity
int val = 0;
if(index <= max){ // first half cycle
   val = index
}else{  // second half cycle
   val = 2 * max - index
}
return min + val // add min
```

This logic should be correct for what you want to do.

Comment: @Teepeemm yup, missed that, fixed!